# Openapi 3.0 empty field regex

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I have following section in OpenApi 3.0 yaml file and want to avoid passing empty strings:

```
CreateFieldXEntity:
  required:
    - field1
  properties:
    field1:
      description: field1
      type: string
      minLength: 1
      pattern: ^(?!\s*$).+
```

However, when I pass

```
"field1":"example text\n"
```

validation error is reported, but when passing

```
"field1":"example text"
```

everything goes ok. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you confirm the following [properties spec](https://swagger.io/specification/#properties): **pattern (This string SHOULD be a valid regular expression, according to the [Ecma-262 Edition 5.1 regular expression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) dialect)** ?

Comment: Well, you can validate regex using regex101.com for example, if I'm getting your point?

Comment: Where do you expect the validation errors to come from? From your backend/middlewhere, from the client app (i.e. Swagger UI?), from some other tool?

Comment: Yaml is used for openapi code generator for java backend, and exception is thrown from controller.

Comment: Can you post the controller code and the regex as it is in the code?

Comment: Btw if you want to test for "at least one non-whitespace character", then `pattern: \S` should be enough. No need for an anchored pattern.

Comment: Well the controller code is not reached, since the validation occurs before, sorry if I wrote it unclear. There is no regex in code, just in yaml file.